# Dar foco nos minutos em input do tipo time

Tags: html, jquery

Existe alguma maneira de "focar" os minutos de um `input` do tipo `time`?

Por padrão, o `focus()` direciona direto para as "horas" que é o início da caixa do `input`, estando vazia ou preenchida:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

  function foco(v) {
    if(v == 1) {
      $('#hora1').focus();
    } else {
      $('#hora2').focus();
    }
  }

</script>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2" onclick="foco(1)"><b>Foco 1</b></button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="foco(2)"><b>Foco 2</b></button>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="row">

    <form id="formX" onsubmit="return false">

      <div id="reg" class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group mr-2">
          <label for="hora1">Hora 1</label>
          <input id="hora1" type="time" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mr-2">
          <label for="hora2">Hora 2</label>
          <input id="hora2" type="time" class="form-control" value="10:10"/>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vc vai usar as horas tb, ou apenas minutos?

Comment: Vou usar os 2... mas sempre focar nos minutos.. vamos supor que são 4 casas: HH:MM... Focaria na primeira casa dos minutos (terceira do input)

Answer (score 1):

> Existe alguma maneira de "focar" os minutos de um input do tipo time?

Programaticamente não existe. Ao focar o elemento `input time`, o primeiro valor (que representa as horas) é automaticamente selecionado. Isso porque o evento `focus` é aplicado ao elemento em si (não em partes dele ou em partes do seu valor). No caso do `time` o valor das horas é selecionado por padrão, como você citou.

Conforme cita a [especificação da W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#time-state), o *user agent* (navegador) **pode ou não** fornecer uma interface para o `time`:

> [...]*If the user agent provides a user interface for selecting a time*[...]

Exceto o Internet Explorer, os outros principais navegadores (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari) fornecem uma interface onde o usuário pode alterar os valores usando as teclas <kbd>↑</kbd> ou <kbd>↓</kbd>, e as teclas <kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd> e <kbd>→</kbd> para selecionar o valor a ser alterado. Mas isso é apenas uma funcionalidade própria do navegador, ou seja, não faz parte de uma especificação ou padronização do HTML ou JavaScript, portanto, cada fabricante pode renderizar o `input time` ao seu gosto (ou não fazer nada, como é o caso do Internet Explorer, que mostra o `input time` como se fosse um `input text`).

Veja as diferenças entre o Edge e o Opera, por exemplo:

**Edge:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Opera:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existem métodos possíveis de selecionar uma parte do valor de um `input text`, mas não é aplicável ao `input time`, conforme também informa o mesmo item do W3C:

> *The following IDL attributes and methods do not apply to the element: checked, files, selectionStart, and selectionEnd IDL attributes;
>   select() and setSelectionRange() methods.*

O texto em inglês acima basicamente está dizendo que não é possível usar métodos JavaScript para selecionar todo o valor do campo ou apenas uma parte, o que é normalmente possível num `input text`:

```js
function sel(i){

   if(i == 1){
      $("[type=text]").select();
   }else{
      $("[type=time]").select();
   }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="sel(1)">Selecionar o input text abaixo</button>
<br>
<input type="text" value="10:10">
<br>
<em>Seleciona todo o valor do campo</em>
<br><br>
<button onclick="sel(2)">Selecionar o input time abaixo</button>
<br>
<input type="time" value="10:10">
<br>
<em>Apenas foca o campo, mas não seleciona todo o valor</em>
```

Resumindo, não existe uma forma de alterar esse comportamento que é próprio do navegador; ou seja, focou o elemento, automaticamente o valor das horas é selecionado.